# Does differential backups and log backups contain users, roles and permission changes?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

Full backup contains database users, roles and permissions.

Does differential backups and log backups contain the above changes?

Comment: Diff and logs contains any changes to the database pages, including pages that contain database level objects. Why would it not include these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as long as you are talking about database level security changes. The following test proves this:

Set up

```
USE [master]
CREATE LOGIN MyLogin WITH PASSWORD = 'My57r0ngp455'
GO

CREATE DATABASE UserTest
GO
```

Create a user, backup, create a role then do a diff backup

```
USE UserTest
GO

CREATE USER MyUser FOR LOGIN MyLogin

BACKUP DATABASE UserTest TO DISK = 'C:\Test\UserTestFull.bak'

CREATE ROLE MyRole
ALTER ROLE MyRole ADD MEMBER MyUser

BACKUP DATABASE UserTest TO DISK = 'C:\Test\UserTestDiff.bak' WITH DIFFERENTIAL
```

Restore the full only and check if the role exists

```
USE [master]
ALTER DATABASE UserTest SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
RESTORE DATABASE UserTest FROM DISK = 'C:\Test\UserTestFull.bak' WITH REPLACE

USE UserTest
GO

SELECT  *
FROM    sys.database_principals p
WHERE   name = 'MyRole' AND
        Type_desc = 'DATABASE_ROLE'
```

Restore the full and diff and check if the role exists

```
USE [master]
ALTER DATABASE UserTest SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
RESTORE DATABASE UserTest FROM DISK = 'C:\Test\UserTestFull.bak' WITH REPLACE, NORECOVERY
RESTORE DATABASE UserTest FROM DISK = 'C:\Test\UserTestDiff.bak'

USE UserTest
GO


SELECT  *
FROM    sys.database_principals p
WHERE   name = 'MyRole' AND
        Type_desc = 'DATABASE_ROLE'
```